# Two div boxes 1 & 2 with text, inside a 3rd div box. Sometimes text in box 1 is longer than text inside box2

Tags: html, css, css-float

Currently I have two div boxes 1 & 2 with text, inside a 3rd div box to contain them together.

> Sometimes text in box 1 is longer than text inside box2 - I want text to flow around box2.
>   Sometimes text in box 2 is longer than text inside box1 - I want text to flow around box1.

All the while text flows in one direction *Right* or *Left*, depends on *Float settings*.

How can box with more text surround box with lesser text?

How is that done using CSS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because they are in two divs they are not able to flow around each other because divs can only have 4 sides, being rectangular or square, they cant wrap around each other.

What you would need to do is only have one inner div, fill it with text and float it, then have the other text outside the floating div but still inside the outermost div, so that basically the free-flowing text's parent is the outermost div, and the inner div has it's own text inside.

This will allow the outer text to flow around the inner div and it's contents, but theres no way to have 2 divs and automatically have them wrap around each other based on content length.

Edit:

If you use jQuery, you will be able to first set the two texts in hidden elements, have the content measured and then append the shorter content to the inner div and the longer content to outside that div so it wraps around it.

Comment: Here's a JSFiddle of CoreyRS' suggestion: [http://jsfiddle.net/LjFLQ/](http://jsfiddle.net/LjFLQ/)

Comment: Wow thanks for the response and it's almost what I need. Notice that the sides switch depending on length? - won't do in my scenario.

Comment: The text need to remain in original side, I'm working on translating right text on to left side, sometimes translation is longer...sometimes it's shorter...Thanks a lot its almost a perfect solution!

Comment: you mean you want it floated in a different direction depending on which text is used?

Comment: i've updated Tim's jsfiddle so that it floats left or right depending on which of the two text is used in the small box.

Comment: When I add more text to the smaller box it jumps from right to left position! can't it stay put and float around left column? - thanks!

Comment: i thought thats what you wanted. The way Tim originally did it kept it on one side. What do you mean "float around" the left column? the outer text can float around the smaller box, but the smaller box cant float around the outer text. look at the fiddle and tell me this: the outer text starts "Lorem ipsum..." and the inner text starts "Fusce vel..." - which text do you want in the corner div and which text in the outer area?

Comment: answer the question i just asked and i'll update it again. but going by what you're saying, it's already doing what you want. The div stays in the corner and is filled with the text of shorter length.

Comment: They should stay where they are. Now IF "Lorem ipsum.." is longer then it should wrap around "Fuscel vel.." But IF "Fuscel vel.." is longer it should wrap around "Lorem ipsum". Without switching sides at all! - is that possible?

Comment: that's exactly what it does now... and has done since tim originally wrote it. you never tested it before commenting. i just tested it and the content swapped perfectly. please tick this answer and use the code tim provided in the fiddle. all you need to do is edit the two sets of text and jquery handles the rest.

Comment: Sorry CoreyRS, at http://jsfiddle.net/LjFLQ/ - "Fuscel vel.."  is at RIGHT Side - Correct? When I add more text to it so it becomes longer than "Lorem ipsum.." and Press the Run Botton "Fuscel vel.." 'swapped perfectly' to the LEFT side - you're right! - But I need it to stay at RIGHT side even when it gets longer and 'somehow' surround "Lorem ipsum.." while it stays allways on Right.

Comment: Thanks for helping, the suggested solution is a great one, but it's impractical to have text intended to be on one side switch sides. @CoreyRS I did test it numerous times, while it did work, it did not keep the text at original location. I only tested the link Tim provided. Was there another? - thanks & sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: sorted perfectly. last time i just put the floats the wrong way around.

Comment: Thanks again @CoreyRS, where is the link? the one at http://http://jsfiddle.net/LjFLQ/ does not behave any different!? I'm missing something? This is my first post & have used this site many times for research...forgive my inexperience...

Comment: nah you aint missing anything. the fiddle keeps reseting itself. i'll do it on a new one - http://jsfiddle.net/K83mQ/5/

Comment: Thank you !!! it's just what I needed...now I need to open the hood of my site...thanks for persisting...